How do I correctly handle onDrop events?
Unfortunately I get this core foundation crash:

There are 0 items on the pasteboard, but 1 drag images. There must be 1 draggingItem per pasteboardItem.

It occurs right after the print statement prints to the console but before I release the mouse.
Tools is a simple enum with this init with circle, square etc in it (which is used by the onDrop.
enum Tools: String, Codable {
    case circle, square

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
         let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
         let rawValue = try container.decode(String.self)
         self = Tools(rawValue: rawValue) ?? .circle
    }
}

// ---------

struct DragInfo: Codable {
    let tool: Tools
    let url: URL

    init(_ tool: Tools,_ url: URL ) {
        self.tool   = tool
        self.url        = url
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        tool = try container.decode(Tools.self, forKey: .tool)
        url = try container.decode(URL.self, forKey: .url)
    }
}

struct DragInfo: Codable {
    let tool: Tools
    let url: URL

    init(_ tool: Tools,_ url: URL ) {
        self.tool   = tool
        self.url        = url
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        tool = try container.decode(Tools.self, forKey: .tool)
        url = try container.decode(URL.self, forKey: .url)
    }
}


.onDrag {
    let draggedData = DragInfo( .furniture, URL(string: "file://abc.txt") ??     URL(fileURLWithPath: ""))
    let data = try? JSONEncoder().encode(draggedData)
    print( "onDrag: \(draggedData)" )
    return NSItemProvider(item: data as NSSecureCoding?, typeIdentifier: "xxx")
}


Can you show a [mcve]? People shouldn't need to make assumptions about other parts of your code.

Are you asking about what the .onDrag is attached to?  The onDrag is attached to a list.  There isn't anything special about it.  I'm dragging list item into a canvas.  I don't believe the canvas even matters or the list since the issue occurs well before a mouse release.

I made some assumptions about your code and it worked for me. Did you actually use typeIdentifier: "xxx" or are you using an actual type identifier that you are trying to hide? I used public.data and I cannot reproduce the problem.

Yes I'm currently using xxx as the typeIdentifier which allows the onDrop to work.  If I use any random com.someApp.... type address it will never call my onDrop.

Perhaps that is what you should be fixing instead. Don’t use a “random” identifier. Use one that you registered, or an existing one, and figure out why onDrop isn’t called.

I don't know the name of my application yet... it's only a month old :)... let me use public.data for now and see if that works.  Wouldn't think that 'registration' would cause this type of issue.  But I'll try anything :).

HAHA, LOL, RoFL... Yeah... using public.data fixed it.  Wow... that is sooo bad.  Sooo unexpected.  TY so much.
